# What is txdvioawpf01, sfy39587stp17 and sfy39587stp16?

Tags: html

While i was scrolling through the code of some websites, I found that a lot of them have the strings txdvioawpf01, sfy39587stp17 and sfy39587stp16 hidden at the end of them. When trying to find out what it means I only found more websites using it. Does anyone know what it means?

```
<div style="display:none">txdvioawpf01</div><div style="display:none">sfy39587stp17</div><div style="display:none">sfy39587stp16</div>
```

Comment: Seeing at least two of these are Drupal 7 sites, I would guess either drupal adding them for test purposes, or some hacker has hacked Drupal and inserts these to test if the site has been cleaned

Comment: Sometimes things like this are added to identity the server hosting the application. This lets testing services (e.g. [Sentry](https://sentry.io/)) know which server is having errors.

Comment: It comes from the former "glazed" theme/theme builder module ( https://www.drupal.org/project/glazed_free) . Not exactly sure about the purpose of these  though, only thing I know the theme has stopped working out of nothing with no traces of any errors after PHP 7.4 upgrade - this is how I found these pieces of code.